# How to create reports based on a SQL database using Visual Studio Express 2013

Tags: c#, sql, windows, visual-studio-2013

I must say I am relatively new to the C# programming language. I've created an application that requires the user to enter some data which is stored in a SQL database. Afterwards he must be able to print some reports based on that data.

My question is: how can I implement such a functionality? I have searched the internet, but I haven't found an answer. I have to mention that I wasn't able to find a way to add the Microsoft Reports tool and template to my project, neither the Crystal Reports tool.

I would be glad if someone could explain to me how to create printable reports using Visual Studio Express 2013 without having to pay money to get Crystal Reports or having to upgrade my Visual Studio suite.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The developer versions of Visual Studio, e.g. Visual Studio Express, have no reporting facilities built in. (It used to ship with a limited version of Crystal Reports, but that is no longer true). To get reports, you'll need to use some third-party reporting framework, of which there are many options.

- SQL Server Reporting Services is probably your best no-cost option, but it will take some work. [SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx) includes Reporting Services, if you get the edition that is called "SQL Server Express with Advanced Services". Of course, if you already have a higher-than-Express version of SQL Server, they all include SSRS as well, you just need to make sure it got installed.
- Crystal Reports still has a developer version: [Crystal Reports, developer edition for Mirosoft Visual Studio](http://www.sap.com/solution/sme/software/analytics/crystal-visual-studio/index.html). My understanding of their licensing model is that developers can use this edition for free, but actually deploying reports to a production environment requires buying at least one license for the Crystal Reports designer.
- Plenty of other third-party reporting toolkits exist; my personal preference from a business standpoint is Developer Express XtraReports, mostly because their support service is top-of-the-line, but again, you have to purchase that suite.

If zero-cost is the deciding factor here, SSRS is really your best option, and it's a pretty good one. There's a free end-user designer that comes with it, but you'll probably want to use the Business Intelligence features. By default, it will install a copy of the Visual Studio 2010 or 2012 Shell, depending on which SQL version you get, called the "Business Intelligence Design Studio", but they have also released [SSDT-BI for Visual Studio 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42313). That will give you the ability to create "SQL Report Projects" in Visual Studio 2013 alongside of your C# projects.

SSRS reports are hosted on the server, so you need to publish them, then access them via the appropriate URL (either in your program, or else just give your client some bookmarks).

Answer (score 0):

One option for you could be [SQL Server Express 2012 Reporting Services](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53931/sql-server-2012-express-with-reporting-services).

This [codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/675762/Call-SSRS-Reports-by-using-Csharp) should help as well.